# Java Swing JPanel: How to forward all method calls to a child JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jpanel, delegation

I want to create a JPanel that overlays a button in the top-right corner but otherwise behaves like any other JPanel.  The only solution I could come up with is something like this:

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
    private final JPanel realPanel = new JPanel();
    private final Button button = new JButton();
    public MyJPanel() {
        super(new OverlayLayout());
        ...layout the realPanel and the button on top of it...
    }
    ... implement all public JPanel methods and delegate to "realPanel"...
}
```

But for this to work, I'd have to override a whole bunch of methods and delegate them to "realPanel".  Is there an easy/easier way than having MyJPanel implement dozens of methods that do nothing but call the same method on the child panel?

Comment: Whoa -- simplify, simplify. Why not extract all logic out of the GUI via M-V-C and make your life (and your code) simpler and easier to manage?

Comment: What is the final goal with this please? :) If you prefer refining how the button looks like (e.g. add a "badge" overlay), the official solution is to implement a custom Button LAF. A simpler solution is to override the paintComponent method of the button to draw whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.  My goal is to create a JTabbedPane with a built-in "help" button in the top right (assume tabs on top) of the tab row space.  Ideally it would extend JTabbedPane, but I couldn't figure out how to do that without having to manually paint a button & handling its click events.  So I opted for an "outer" JPanel container with a JTabbedPane & a JButton inside (layed out via OverlayLayout) and having all layout/add/remove operations forwarded to the contained JTabbedPane.

Answer (score 0):

Swing mouse events are hit-tested and forwarded to the component below the mouse. You need either:

1. implement those listeners (oh and also translate mouse event coordinates which are relative to the topmost panel)
2. instead of using a panel, decorate the button by customizing its painting (e.g. override `paintComponent`, or implement a custom LAF). In this case, the customization is still the same component, so the button will receive all the mouse events.

PS: It is always a good idea to explain *why* you wish to achieve a goal, instead of just pushing for achieving a certain solution. There are more solutions if the real problem is understood.

Comment: A component which is not opaque (transparent) will allow mouse events to pass through it to components below it - I tested it by creating a transparent component an overriding the `paintComponent` to paint various levels of transparent colors from fully transparent to fully opaque without issue - however, I have no idea what the OP is asking or why they are trying to achieve

Comment: *"It is always a good idea to explain _why_ you wish to achieve a goal, instead of just pushing for achieving a certain solution."* See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)